# How to run code when resuming an activity after a swipe back gesture from another activity in WearOS?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have three activities

1. MainActivity
2. StartActivity
3. EndActivity

When the app loads it opens MainActivty, there are two buttons called Start and End. Clicking on Start takes to StartActivity and End takes to EndActivity. From both these activities, I can swipe back to MainActivity. I want to execute code in MainActivity when the others are swiped away and the MainActivity is revealed.

So far I have tried OnResume and OnRestart events with no success. Please suggest something that I can try?

Please note: I am not interested about the Activity from which I come back from. Only need to execute code when the MainActivity is resumed.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : WearableActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStartActivity) as Button
        btnStart.setOnClickListener{
            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, StartActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }



        val btnEnd = findViewById(R.id.btnEndActivity) as Button
        btnEnd.setOnClickListener{
            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, EndActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled()
    }

    fun onRestart(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestart();
        val btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStartActivity) as Button
        btnStart.text = MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start.toString() +":" + MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start.toString()

    }

}
```

StartActivity

```
class StartActivity : WearableActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)
        val pickerStart = findViewById(R.id.timePickerStart) as TimePicker

        pickerStart.setIs24HourView(true)
        pickerStart.setHour(MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start)
        pickerStart.setMinute(MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start)

        pickerStart.setOnTimeChangedListener(TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
            MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start = hourOfDay
            MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start =minute

        })

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled()
    }
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed()
        finish()
    }
}
```

EndActivity is similar to StartActivity

Link to Code: [Layout and code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/doqi77f2vep2dg9/AAA_3CLyG_Mn0AP59xDPMECva?dl=0)

Comment: To make it easier for people to help answer your question, and for people to benefit from the solution, please post the relevant code as text rather than linking to it. (The same goes for your answer.)

Comment: @TofferJ Which part should I post? Should I put the layout and all that code here? Because I have no idea what the issue was when I started. Now I have a working solution but not sure if any of it is right way to do it. I just achieved what I wanted to do.

Comment: Please post any code related to your question. For the above, post any code related to the Activities life cycles that you've tried using to make it work. For the answer below, post any code that can help others understand how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch StartActivity and EndActivity using

```
startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

you will get a callback once they finish (i.e. dismissed by the user and returns to MainActivity)

```
onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Since you don't care about the activity you come back from you can ignore most of the arguments and just execute the code you need to run.

More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed to do this using onResume method. The issue I had was that I didn’t use override. I was planning to post the working code here. But thought to wait until someone responds.

Comment: Will this work even when the start activity is dismissed?

Comment: The problem with onResume that it also gets called for other reasons, e.g. if another activity takes focus. onActivityResult will only be called when you return from one of your own activities. Not sure what you mean with MainActivity being dismissed. My assumption is that MainActivity will launch the other activities and stay in the background, waiting for the user to return to it. If you want code to run when MainActivity is being dismissed, the answer is no. Then you have to also add that code to the onDestroy method of MainActivity (to ensure that it only runs when it's being dismissed).

Comment: I have asked when I dismiss(swipe back to Main Activity) StartActivity, not the main activity. I know it is confusing because that name is already taken by android when someone starts an activity.

Comment: What I've suggested above will give you a way to execute code when the user dismisses either StartActivity or EndActivity, and returns to MainActivity. It will also ensure that the code is executed only when the user returns to MainActivity from one of your sub-activities. Putting the code in onResume instead will most likely have unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work. But not sure if it is the right way.

Screen record of the App - [TimeDifference Screen Record](https://photos.app.goo.gl/jVGoE8MnLa3iifbN8)

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : WearableActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //Log.d(TAG,"onCreate: called")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start =0
        MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start = 0
        MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_end =0
        MyApplication.Companion.g_min_end = 0

        val btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStartActivity) as Button
        btnStart.setOnClickListener{
            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, StartActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


        val btnEnd = findViewById(R.id.btnEndActivity) as Button
        btnEnd.setOnClickListener{
            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, EndActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        //Log.d(TAG,"onResume: called")
        super.onResume();
        val btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStartActivity) as Button
        val btnEnd = findViewById(R.id.btnEndActivity) as Button
        val txtCalc = findViewById(R.id.txtResult) as TextView
        val StartHour = MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start
        val StartMin = MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start
        val EndHour = MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_end
        val EndMin = MyApplication.Companion.g_min_end
        val DifferenceMinutes : Int
        val DiffHour : Int
        val DiffMin : Int

        if (StartHour + StartMin !=  0 ) {
            btnStart.text =
                StartHour.toString().padStart(2,'0') + ":" + StartMin.toString().padStart(2,'0')

        }

        if (EndHour + EndMin !=  0 ) {
            btnEnd.text =
                EndHour.toString().padStart(2,'0') + ":" + EndMin.toString().padStart(2,'0')

        }
        if (StartHour + StartMin !=  0 &&
            EndHour + EndMin !=  0 ){
            //txtCalc.textSize = 20f
            var TotalStartMinutes = StartHour * 60 + StartMin
            var TotalEndMinutes = EndHour * 60 + EndMin
            if(TotalEndMinutes> TotalStartMinutes) {
                DifferenceMinutes = TotalEndMinutes - TotalStartMinutes
            }else{
                DifferenceMinutes = TotalStartMinutes - TotalEndMinutes
            }
            DiffHour = DifferenceMinutes / 60
            DiffMin = DifferenceMinutes % 60

            if (DiffHour == 0 && DiffMin == 0){
                txtCalc.text = "No Difference!!"
            }else if (DiffHour == 0){
                txtCalc.text = "$DiffMin m"
            } else if(DiffMin == 0){
                txtCalc.text = "$DiffHour h"
            } else{
                txtCalc.text = "$DiffHour h and $DiffMin m"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StartActivity

```
class StartActivity : WearableActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)
        val pickerStart = findViewById(R.id.timePickerStart) as TimePicker

        pickerStart.setIs24HourView(true)
        pickerStart.setHour(MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start)
        pickerStart.setMinute(MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start)

        pickerStart.setOnTimeChangedListener(TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
            MyApplication.Companion.g_hour_start = hourOfDay
            MyApplication.Companion.g_min_start =minute

        })

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled()
    }
}
```

For Global Variables

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        var g_hour_start = 0
        var g_min_start = 0
        var g_hour_end = 0
        var g_min_end = 0
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // initialization code here
    }
}
```

EndActivity is similar to StartActivity

[Code and Layout for the WearOS app](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jbnvzilwozu26xg/AAA-isN7oHWu4B4Y-6IVD05Xa?dl=0)